# Let $f: [0, \infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and strictly increasing function such that $f^4(x) =\int^x_0 t^2f^3(t)\,dt$ for all $x > 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

Problem :

Let $f: [0, \infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and strictly increasing function such that $f^4(x) =\int^x_0 t^2f^3(t)\,dt$ for all $x > 0$. Find the area enclosed by $y = f(x)$, the $x$ axis and the ordinates at $x = -1$ and $x = 4$.

My approach :

$$f^4(x) =\int^x_0 t^2f^3(t)\,dt $$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$ we get

$$4f^3(x) f'(x) =x^2f^3(x)\implies f'(x) =\frac{x^2}{4}$$

Now integrating both sides : 
$f(x) =\frac{x^3}{12}+C$ where $C$ is a constant.

Now what to do next please suggest how to get $f(x)$ only,  thanks.

Comment: btw it does not make sense to define $f$ only for $x\in[0,\infty)$ and then ask for the integral over $x\in [-1,4]$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider what possible values $f(0)$ could have, using the fact that
$$
f^4(x) = \int\limits_0^x t^2 f^3(t) dt.
$$
Use this to find $C$.